# Using notepad++ for finding and replacing complex statement - regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

Now :-

```
SELECT @ptrval = TEXTPTR(COLUMN_NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME   WHERE <condition>
UPDATETEXT TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME @ptrval NULL NULL @textpart;
```

Change to:-

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME set COLUMN_NAME .write(@textpart,null,null) WHERE <condition>;
```

Answer (score 0):

With information you provided I've managed to come up with this:

```
^.*(?<=from )([a-z_]+).*where\s+([a-z]+)\s?\n?.*\1\.([a-z_]+).*@([a-z]*)
```

Replace by:

```
update \1 set \3 .write(\4, null, null) where \2
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rT1uE2/2

If it won't work please provide more info.

**EDIT** pattern and demo have been updated

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick reply and for looking into it. The thing is it is working but I am having a new line character after the condition in the string, I thing you didnt consider that.

Answer (score 0):

This did exactly what I wanted:

```
^SELECT @ptrval = TEXTPTR.*(?<=from )([a-zA-Z_]+).*where(.+)\r\nUPDATETEXT \1\.([a-zA-Z_]+) @ptrval NULL NULL @textpart;$

update \1 set \3 .write\(@textpart, null, null\) where \2;
```